# How to zoom to selected layers or selected features with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, extents, zoom

I have a map with different vector layers (sources are geojson files) on it, which are grouped in on array as it follows

```
layers_group = [];
layers_group.push(layer_1, layer_2);

source_group = [];
source_group.push(source_1,source_2);
```

layers are added to the `var map` with the function

```
map.addLayer(ocean_map);
map.addLayer(layer_1);
map.addLayer(layer_2);
```

Layers' style is by default transparent, and it gets a different style when a specific layer or a specific feature included in the geojson file are selected.

I have hence 2 different codes for selecting a layer or a feature in the layer. My question is how to add the instruction to zoom in when the selection is completed?

My selecting codes are as follows:

**Select a specific layer**

```
 $("#region_select").change(function() {
    //it starts the function to change styles according to the selection made
      var selectedRegion = $("#region_select").val();
      var index;
      for (index = 0; index < layers_group.length; ++index){
          var name = layers_group[index].get('name');
          if(selectedRegion === name){
          layers_group[index].setVisible(true);
          document.getElementById("messageBar").innerHTML = layers_group[index].get('name');
        } else if (selectedRegion ==="all"){
            var index;
            for (index = 0; index < layers_group.length; ++index){
                layers_group[index].setVisible(true);
            }    
        }
        else {
          layers_group[index].setVisible(false);
        }

      };
    });
```

**Select a specific feature within the file**

```
    $("#species_auto").change(function() {
    //it starts the function to change styles according to the selection made
        var selectedSpecies = $("#species_auto").val();
        console.log('selectedSpecies',selectedSpecies);
        var index;
        for (index = 0; index < source_group.length; ++index){
            source_group[index].forEachFeature(function(feat){

            //source.forEachFeature(function(feat){
                console.log(feat);
                console.log(feat.get('Species'))
                console.log(feat.get('Species').indexOf(selectedSpecies));


    //if substring(selected text) exist within fetaure property('Speices)
    //should return any value other than -1
                if (feat.get('Species').indexOf(selectedSpecies)!=-1) {
    //so set the style on each feature
                feat.setStyle(selectStyle);
                } else {
    //and if doesnt exist switch back to the deafult style
                feat.setStyle(transparentStyle);
                }
            });
        };

    });
```

In the first case I tried to use

```
var extent = layers_group[index].getSource().getExtent();
map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
```

and in the second case

```
var extent = feat.getGeometry().getExtent();
map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
```

both of them were written within the if() condition, but they didn't work. The following error was reported

TypeError: map.getView is not a function

Does somebody have a suggestion?